Converting MGRS to Lat/Long creates inaccuracy from expected position
I have a table with the following data.



Location
Easting
Northing




Point A
7482
0837


Point B
7675
0576



I think these locations use the Military Grid Reference System (MGRS).
If this is true, then the Easting/Northing of their location can be re-written as MGRS grid references since I know the locations are within grid zone 50JLL.



Location
Easting




Point A
50JLL74820837


Point B
50JLL76750576



When I convert these MGRS grid references to latitude and longitude they are often a few hundred metres away from where I expect them to be.
For example:
Point A's raw data: 7482 0837
Point A as MGRS: 50JLL74820837
Point A as decimal degrees, converted from MGRS: -31.5528660 115.6811311 (224.08 meters inaccuracy)
Point A's real location as confirmed in person: -31.55128 115.68259
Is this inaccuracy as result of the conversion between the raw data, MGRS grid reference and decimal degrees, or is more likely that my raw data is inaccurate to begin with?

Is inaccuracy random or constant offset?

MRGS is a gridding algorithm. For 10m squares, the maximum error is sqrt(100+100) = 14.14m if you have ten times that, something else is wrong.

I get closer to your converted-from-MGRS lat-lon values if I use the Australian National Spheroid/ellipsoid, rather than WGS84 or GRS80, -31.552711 115.681152 using NGA's GEOTRANS 3.9 and identifying the MGRS strings as AGD66 and the output lat/lon as AGD84. If I use AGD84 or AGD66 as both in/out the numbers are farther off. What software are you using?

And what are the software settings?

@TomazicM The inaccuracy changes, but the converted coordinates are generally est. 215m SW of their expected position.

@mkennedy I haven't been using an application so far - I've been using this website: https://www.earthpoint.us/convert.aspx. Do you recommend I download GEOTRANS 3.9? Also, I'm having trouble understanding your first comment, is there a way you could explain it to me as a beginner? Thanks for your help.

@TigerTen MGRS is an alphanumeric representation of UTM which uses transverse Mercator projection. Part of the TM math includes ellipsoid values that's being used. Results will vary depending on the ellipsoid so it's one thing to check if you're not getting the results you expect. re: geotrans it is from the considered canonical for NGA.

I realized as I was writing my third long comment that I really needed to try to make an answer. This isn't a perfect answer, but a start.
MGRS is a gridded system based on UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator) coordinates. While MGRS was originally designed to be used with WGS84 coordinates by the US military, it's possible to generate MGRS strings using any geographic coordinate reference system/UTM combination. Using a non-WGS84 GeoCRS can significantly affect MGRS strings.
Some questions you need to answer:

What coordinate reference system are the MGRS based upon? Is there any metadata? Any mention of a datum/GeoCRS anywhere?
What coordinate reference system are the in-person, real lat-lon coordinates based upon?
Possibly important, how accurate are the in-person, real lat-lon coordinates?

Earthpoint and GEOTRANS will default to using the WGS84 GeoCRS which uses the WGS84 ellipsoid. GEOTRANS does support different GeoCRS when calculating MGRS strings. It  can also convert between GeoCRS (like WGS84 lat-lon to AGD66 MGRS).
The positions are in Australia. Australia has 4 datums/GeoCRS of interest: AGD66 and AGD84 which use the Australian National Spheroid; GDA94 and GDA2020 which use GRS80 ellipsoid (almost identical to WGS84). The latter two should match WGS84 (any version) within 2 meters. Because the results are more different than that, it's more likely that either AGD66 or AGD84 are the source of the MGRS strings . Unfortunately, the positions are in an Australian state that did adopt AGD84 (a few states stayed on AGD66 until GDA94) so the MGRS strings could be in either one.
I suggest using GEOTRANS to run some tests. Take the in-person coordinates, assume they are WGS84 and convert to AGD66 and to AGD84 MGRS strings and see if either match.

Thank you for your answer. I'll use GEOTRANS later today and try some of your recommendations.
